# How do I manipulate the output of a PHP script when it is already manipulated by another (plug-in) script?

Tags: php

I take it you are confused. So am I, but I'll try to formulate this as well as I can.

The content management system I use has a third-party plug-in installed that manipulates the output of the pages produced by the CMS. That's what it's supposed to do, and that's why I installed it, but there's one small part of those manipulations that I need to get rid of.

The plug-in looks for the `</title>` tag in the HTML output and then adds an unwanted tag right after it (by replacing `</title>` with `</title><unwanted tag>`).

You might think, why not just dig into the plug-in source and comment out that particular function? Well, that's the kicker: the plug-in is encoded with Zend Guard, so I can't make heads nor tails of its source, and unfortunately the developer is not willing to assist.

One other manipulation that I *was* able to get rid of by myself, was the extra (and again unwanted) HTTP header it set for every page.

The Zend-encoded PHP file is loaded by a regular PHP file, and I was able to unset the above mentioned header by adding the following bit of code to the very bottom of this 'load file', before `?>`:

`header_remove("X-Enhanced-By");`

It works splendidly, but that was about as far as my experience and research could take me.

The last thing, then, that I need to undo, is the manipulation of the title tag. I temporarily worked around it by changing all my `</title>` tags to `</title >`, but that seems hardly a proper workaround.

If I can unset the header by placing `header_remove("X-Enhanced-By");` right before `?>`, does that mean I can also use that same area to undo the addition of the unwanted tag after `</title>`?

Let's assume the plug-in replaces `</title>` with `</title><base href="http://www.example.com/" />` on every page that is put out by the CMS.

How would I go about undoing that?

Comment: Can you access the raw output on every page before it's send (e.g. through a hook)?. That way you could replace it via a regexp. Post some code and we'll know more..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the CMS framework. Basically you should be able to create a hook/plugin which captures the output at a higher level than your plugin then regex the tags out.

I get it that the plugin installed already does that so it should be "doable"

Comment: It appears that the plug-in is running on top of the CMS framework, rather than within it, so any attempt to regex the tags out from within the CMS files is pointless, considering that the plug-in apparently adds the tags after PHP finishes. So they don't get added on the PHP level, but probably through the Zend Engine, and since I cannot read the encoded files, there don't seem to be any options left.